# Is there a standard set of terms describing different git ref names/refstrings parts/forms

Tags: git, azure-devops

In short, what are the standard agreed upon terms for different "parts" of git refs.

Assuming some branch `refs/heads/myBranches/subBranch`, what should

1. `refs/heads/myBranches/subBranch`
2. `heads/myBranches/subBranch`
3. `heads`
4. `myBranches/subBranch`

be called?

***after [torek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59112582/3745022) and rereading docs once more I would say that***

1. `refs/heads/myBranches/subBranch` - **fully qualified ref** (to avoid confusion with `SPECIAL` names like `HEAD` and etc.). Probably even just `full ref` for brevity.
2. `heads/myBranches/subBranch` - **?**, though [gitrevisions](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) `otherwise, refs/remotes/<refname> if it exists;` consider it to be `refname` (or is it only for refs/remotes? Or perhaps I am just trying to read additional meaning when there is none, am I?)
3. `heads` - **namespace**
4. `myBranches/subBranch` - **refname**

So, am I correct in calling them so, and what should the `heads/myBranches/subBranch`-like "ref" be called like?

---

A bit of context, if needed.

We work a lot with [.NET client libraries for Azure DevOps Services (and TFS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=azure-devops) and [there](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient) is unfortunately not always enough consistency between how branch names are represented/should be passed.

Branch name can be either of `refs/heads/branch`, `heads/branch` and `branch` in API DTOs/parameters.

So to avoid a lot of obvious errors, we are using the following class as part of our anti-corruption layer. Still, I am not exactly happy that the terms we used may be a bit non-standard.

```
public class GitRefString : IEquatable<GitRefString>
{
    public static class Types
    {
        public const string Head = "head";
        public const string Tags = "tags";
    }   

    public static GitRefString Head(string name)
    {
        return new GitRefString(Types.Head, name);
    }

    public GitRefString(string type, string name)
    {
        Type = type;
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Type { get; }
    public string Name { get; }

    public string Ref => $"refs/{Type}/{Name}";

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to invent your own terminology, depending on your purposes.

Internally, Git calls all of these things (`refs/*`) *references* or *refs*.  There are special reference names `HEAD`, `ORIG_HEAD`, `MERGE_HEAD`, `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD`, and so on as well.  Whether these count as "refs" is a bit questionable, but [the gitglossary](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary) says that ref is:

> A name that begins with `refs/` (e.g. `refs/heads/master`) that points to an object name or another ref (the latter is called a symbolic ref). ...
>
> There are a few special-purpose refs that do not begin with `refs/`. The most notable example is `HEAD`.

So I would call these *refs* as well, but internally, these are sometimes called *pseudorefs*.

Refs are divided into *name spaces*, and those under `refs/heads/` are *branch names* or *heads*.  Those under `refs/tags/` are *tag names*.  Those under `refs/remotes/` are *remote-tracking names*.  (Git calls them *remote-tracking branch names* or even just *remote-tracking branches*, but doing so risks conflating them with actual branch names, so I prefer the term *remote-tracking name*.)  Each remote has its own separate remote-tracking name space: `refs/remotes/origin/` lists the names copied from `origin`, while `refs/remotes/fred/` lists the names copied from `fred`.

Note that some refs are *per-worktree*.  The gitglossary claims that only `HEAD` and `refs/bisect/` names are per-worktree, but that's [demonstrably false: the source code actually tests three `refs/` spaces](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d9f6f3b6195a0ca35642561e530798ad1469bd41/refs.c#L721-L727).  Fortunately the use case for these is rare enough that you can *probably* just avoid considering them entirely.

If you wish to write code that fully-qualifies a ref (e.g., turns `master` into `refs/heads/master` as appropriate), and want to do it the same way that Git does, the official rules are listed in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) as a six step process:

1. If *`$GIT_DIR/<refname>`* exists, that is what you mean (this is usually useful only for `HEAD`, `FETCH_HEAD`, `ORIG_HEAD`, `MERGE_HEAD` and `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD`);
2. otherwise, *`refs/<refname>`* if it exists;
3. otherwise, *`refs/tags/<refname>`* if it exists;
4. otherwise, *`refs/heads/<refname>`* if it exists;
5. otherwise, *`refs/remotes/<refname>`* if it exists;
6. otherwise, *`refs/remotes/<refname>/HEAD`* if it exists.

Unfortunately, this is oversimplified: when you use `git checkout`, for instance, the name is tried *first* as a `refs/heads/` branch name, even if an otherwise identical tag-name exists.  Hence `git checkout foo` obtains a different commit from that shown by `git show foo` when `foo` is both branch and tag name.

(This also fails to cover per-worktree name resolution, which doesn't quite use the above rules.)

Programmatically, your best bet is probably to *require* fully-qualified names in all but one or a few routines.  These special routines are the ones that change less-qualified names (such as `heads/foo` or `tags/foo` for the ambiguous-`foo` case) into fully qualified names.  Here you can say: *prefer branch or tag* as an option, so that you can handle a "tag-oriented" command by saying that you prefer the tag, and a "branch-oriented" command by saying that you prefer the branch.  (And, if you need to worry about per-worktree refs, you're probably doing something you shouldn't. )

Comment: Thanks, that's a pretty comprehensive answer about git refs overall, just our scenario is that `GitRefString` is always `refs/(heads|tags)/name` (with API there is no concept of local/remote - if need arises those can be added as optional parts). `require fully-qualified names ` is what we try to do with `GitRefString` to hide all the multitudes of ref name/parts that API uses.

Comment: I have also edited the question to incorporate information from this answer. If nothing better appears, I'd probably go with names/terms from your links.